# how to reproduce the images gallery effect of duckduckgo search with css only

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I'm trying to create a gallery for images of every shapes, that would act like the image search in duckduckgo desktop browser : the images fill each entire row.

To achieve that, duckduckgo keeps one constant height and slightly reduce the horizontal size of the images to have a perfect width. I want to do it in pure css

Here is an exemple if you search for fish images in duckduckgo : https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fish&t=newext&atb=v246-1&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

You can see how each images keep their ratio aproximatively, but are modified a little bit to fit perfectly the entire view width, that gives a well organized image gallery with all kind of images sizes

**first attempt : images stretch**

I began by using the `flex: 1;` property, or in my case to be precise : `flex: 1 1 0;`, for the `flex-grow` property, this gives me something where the images become larger to fill the entire row, but some of them stretch too hard so at certain size of windows it's really weird

**second attempt : images inside a box**

then I tried to put the images inside a box, that would do the visual effect of growing, without changing the width of the image, but it's not really nice

**third attempt : reduce the image by cutting**

so then I tried to reproduce the method of duckduckgo, shrinking the images instead of growing them. I thought I would do it easily with flex-shrink, but I couldn't make it work, so I manually put the image in a box that is `-30px` smaller each size, left and right, and they grow automatically with flex, revealing the hidden part of the image.

Sometimes it grows more than the image width so we see the background, that's ok, but it's not better looking because some images get really too thin

**fourth attempt : reduce with a minimum**

so i tried with a minimum size, it's better, but still not satisfying at all

```css
/*GALERY*/
/*first gallery and default settings*/
.galery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.galery .card {
    display: flex;
    /*direction column for the text under the img*/
    flex-direction: column;
    /*flex-grow is what let the cards containing
    the images grow until it fills the entire row*/
    flex: 1 1 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
.galery .card img {
    /*a constant height for the effect of all images aligned*/
    height: 200px;
}
.galery .card p {
    /*the text on the left*/
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.galery .card > * {
    /*vertical margin of 5px is for the gap between <img> and <p>*/
    /*horizontal margin of 0px is what makes the img
    stretch to fit the div element*/
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.galery::after {
    /*this pseudo-element is used to create an empty area after
    the last card to avoid it to grow on an entire line*/
    content: "";
    flex: 10;
}
/*second gallery : space around the img*/
.galery.space .card .image_background {
    /*the div .img_background is used to make the
    frame visible when the img do not stretch*/
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}
.galery.space .card .image_background img {
    /*margin auto avoid the image to stretch*/
    margin: auto;
}
/*third gallery : images cutted*/
/*images are inside an element that cut them horizontally
so when flex-grow expend them they fill the frame without
empty space most of the case*/
.galery.cut .card .image_background {
    display: flex;
    /*this wrapper takes 100% of the width and hides the img overflow*/
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}
.galery.cut .card .image {
    /*this wrapper contains the img and has a width independent of the parent element*/
    margin: auto;
}
.galery.cut .card .image img {
    /*because of this negative margin, the wrapper .image is
    thinner than the image, of 60px, so it can grow with less
    chance of exceeding the img size*/
    margin: auto -30px;
}
/*fourth gallery : minwidth to avoid having really small img*/
.galery.minwidth .card {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- the html code is just 4 times the same gallery of 17 img,
with different div elements to wrap what is needed for the css -->

<p>_images horizontal stretch_____________________________________________</p>

<div class="galery">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2010/July/Thumbnail/727fish-thmb.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0Js4q23LxSc/S9z_EhlbSuI/AAAAAAAABE0/frTJgUQiewg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/banggai+cardinalfish.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/koi-fish.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_87/cy_0/cw_450/ch_450/w_162/APL/uploads/2014/06/10-aquarium-fish-for-every-budget-pictures1.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/killifish.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/scat_silver_110217b3_w0090.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/muranozoo/_/rsrc/1371868925930/fish-invertebrates/fish-invertebrates-2/FormiaMarlin.jpg?height=200&width=148">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/blue_leopard_angelfish_151204a2_w0090.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/cat-fish.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/bett.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.aboutfishonline.com/images/anemonefish2.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/neon.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <p>_images horizontal extra space_________________________________________</p>

<div class="galery space">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2010/July/Thumbnail/727fish-thmb.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0Js4q23LxSc/S9z_EhlbSuI/AAAAAAAABE0/frTJgUQiewg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/banggai+cardinalfish.png">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/koi-fish.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_87/cy_0/cw_450/ch_450/w_162/APL/uploads/2014/06/10-aquarium-fish-for-every-budget-pictures1.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/killifish.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/scat_silver_110217b3_w0090.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/muranozoo/_/rsrc/1371868925930/fish-invertebrates/fish-invertebrates-2/FormiaMarlin.jpg?height=200&width=148">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/blue_leopard_angelfish_151204a2_w0090.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/cat-fish.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/bett.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.aboutfishonline.com/images/anemonefish2.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/neon.jpg">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>_images horizontaly cut________________________________________________</p>

<div class="galery cut">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2010/July/Thumbnail/727fish-thmb.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0Js4q23LxSc/S9z_EhlbSuI/AAAAAAAABE0/frTJgUQiewg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/banggai+cardinalfish.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/koi-fish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_87/cy_0/cw_450/ch_450/w_162/APL/uploads/2014/06/10-aquarium-fish-for-every-budget-pictures1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/killifish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/scat_silver_110217b3_w0090.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/muranozoo/_/rsrc/1371868925930/fish-invertebrates/fish-invertebrates-2/FormiaMarlin.jpg?height=200&width=148">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/blue_leopard_angelfish_151204a2_w0090.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/cat-fish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/bett.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.aboutfishonline.com/images/anemonefish2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/neon.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>_images horizontaly cut with minimum width_____________________________</p>

<div class="galery cut minwidth">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://media.mercola.com/ImageServer/Public/2010/July/Thumbnail/727fish-thmb.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0Js4q23LxSc/S9z_EhlbSuI/AAAAAAAABE0/frTJgUQiewg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/banggai+cardinalfish.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/koi-fish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_87/cy_0/cw_450/ch_450/w_162/APL/uploads/2014/06/10-aquarium-fish-for-every-budget-pictures1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/killifish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/scat_silver_110217b3_w0090.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/muranozoo/_/rsrc/1371868925930/fish-invertebrates/fish-invertebrates-2/FormiaMarlin.jpg?height=200&width=148">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://aquariumfish.net/images_01/blue_leopard_angelfish_151204a2_w0090.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.liveanimalslist.com/fish/images/cat-fish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/bett.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://rolfingunshelved.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-game-of-thrones-book-cover.jpeg?w=98&h=150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.aboutfishonline.com/images/anemonefish2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image_background">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.webindia123.com/pets/fish/neon.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

do you have any idea how to do that better ?

What i'm really trying to do is a gallery of images in witch i could put any images without specific settings, no matter its size, if you have another design solution than the duckduckgo version, i'm listening

Comment: If you want them all the same height then would width auto be what you need or are you after a max width too?

Comment: @AHaworth i don't see how `width: auto;` or `max-width` would give me what i want ? on what element would you place it ?

Comment: Ah, I may have misinterpreted what you want. I thought it was the img you were concerned about.

Comment: it is, but the difficulty is to let them make a row that fills the entire view-width, eventhough they have different size. It cannot be done without changing the size a little bit, and duckduckgo does that in the background, but i try to do it in css. Flex-grow makes something similar, unfortunately the best thing would it to shrink instead of grow, as duckduckgo do. But i'm having trouble doing so :/ I don't see how img width:auto would help here, but maybe i miss something ?